# POSKeyError during migration

Tags: migration, plone

Migration from plone 3.3.2 to plone 4.2.1 fails with PosKeyError. I've tried recipes from this article http://plonechix.blogspot.com/2009/12/definitive-guide-to-poskeyerror.html. 
I've run error_finder snippet, but it didn't give me any execeptions.  I've also tried to take object in debugger using `app.mysite._p_jar[p64(oid)]` - also no success, it fails with the same error.

How can I delete the broken object or at least get more info about object (e.g. its class name or location)?

Full traceback:

```
POSKeyError('\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0ey=',)
(Also, the following error occurred while attempting to render the standard error message, please see the event log for full details:
An operation previously failed, with traceback: 
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.16-py2.7.egg/ZServer/PubCore/ZServerPublisher.py", line 31, in __init__
  response=b) 
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.16-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py", line 443, in publish_module
  environ, debug, request, response)
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.16-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py", line 237, in publish_module_standard
  response = publish(request, module_name, after_list, debug=debug)
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.16-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/Publish.py", line 134, in publish
  transactions_manager.commit()
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.16-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 301, in commit
  transaction.commit()
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transaction-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/transaction/_manager.py", line 89, in commit
  return self.get().commit()
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transaction-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 336, in commit
  t, v, tb = self._saveAndGetCommitishError()
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transaction-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 329, in commit
  self._commitResources()
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transaction-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 443, in _commitResources
  rm.commit(self)
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 572, in commit
  oid, serial, transaction)
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/ZODB/BaseStorage.py", line 416, in checkCurrentSerialInTransaction
  committed_tid = self.getTid(oid)
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 770, in getTid
  with self._lock:
File "/Users/makmak/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 403, in _lookup_pos
  raise POSKeyError(oid)
POSKeyError: 0x0e793d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fsrefs.py to find the bad object.

A very short article on using it is: http://nathanvangheem.com/news/fixing-broken-zodb-object-references

Comment: Тhe error disappeared after clear and rebuild portal_catalog on the plone 3 site. I think, the broken object was an one of catalog brains and was removed during rebuild. Not sure but it seems that fsrefs script doesn't scan catalog brains, that's why it didn't give me any output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the [same issue I just ran into](http://rpatterson.net/blog/poskeyerror-during-commit) which happens if a savepoint is rolled back that included adding an object to the catalog.  I think this is a bug in the ZODB but you can workaround it by addressing whatever is rolling back a savepoint, in this case that's the migration of files and images to blobs.  So if you fix what's keeping those files or images from successfully migrating to BLOBs (or just delete them) then it should succeed.